# How to fix file path case?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a set of local paths, and some of them are capitalized (C:\SOMEDIR\SOMEFILE.TXT). I need to convert them to their real names (as shown in Explorer). Suggest a way plz.

Comment: What do you mean by *real name*?  In Windows, there is a slippery slope of what a real name might be.  On a FAT file system, the 8.3 name is more real than the LFN version.  On NTFS, all filenames are equal—they just have different namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#short_vs._long_names): short names vs. long name?

Note that Explorer applies some tricky conversions to the file names. You easiest shot is to test it all and make your own function for the purpose.

Otherwise, you can try to access via OLE the Explorer's functions to list files in directory. But that is *VERY* painful and error prone to code. (Why I guess MS has given up in the end and provided the functions I have linked to above in Win2K).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could always use `OpenFile` to get a handle, and then use the method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the filename from that handle. I haven't tried it, but it seems likely to give the "explorer name"

[Obtaining a File Name From a File Handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366789%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

I don't know of any direct API call to do this in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your file path to [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx), the resulting `WIN32_FIND_DATA.cFileName` will be in the correct case as read from the file system.